# Windows Dissapear in Mission Control (Mac OS Catalina 10.15.5)

Tags: catalina, dock, mission-control

Windows will shrink/reduce to nothing while using the Mission Control feature. This applies to both the button and the three finger gesture. No other workspaces are open, and I have attempted to both restart the system and the dock, to no success. `defaults read com.apple.dock` only shows that `showMissionControlGestureEnabled` is enabled.

Unfortunately, I lost track of when this first appeared. If someone could nudge me in the right direction to diagnose the issue, I could tinker.

Comment: Which gesture are you performing? Three fingers down or up? Up -> app overview. Down -> show windows of the same app.

Comment: Three fingers up. I think you are eluding to Mission Control (up) and Exposé (down). As I mentioned above, the same effect occurs pressing the Mission Control button

Comment: Do you have Google's Backup and Sync installed?

Comment: No google products on this system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is terrible, the issue resolved itself and I do not know what did it. My general usage and workflow did not change. No restart was done since posting this question, and I've attempted to recreate my previous usage.

Apologies to any who come across this issue expecting a satisfactory solution.

Comment: I had this problem - it was due to Steam running (and perhaps after running a game in full screen mode). If I closed down the Steam client, functionality was restored.

Comment: Thank you @Richard. Steam was my issue as well.

Answer (score 1):

Found a simple workaround. Open activity monitor and kill the Dock process, Mission Control is a child process and gets rebooted without rebooting the Mac. Fixed it instantly.